# Can't find C# executable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I created a new project in Visual Studio 2019 and named it `SimpleCSharpApp`. Wrote a simple HelloWorld application and compiled in Debug Mode. Now I need the executable (the `.exe` file to be more exact). It is supposed to be in `SimpleCSharpApp/bin/Debug`, but it isn't there. There's a single directory named `netcoreapp2.1` which contains the following files:

```
SimpleCSharpApp.deps.json  
SimpleCSharpApp.dll  
SimpleCSharpApp.pdb  
SimpleCSharpApp.runtimeconfig.dev.json  
SimpleCSharpApp.runtimeconfig.json
```

How can I find the executable?

Comment: The executable is in the folder `netcoreapp2.1`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes it is not. See the edit please

Comment: If it contains only a DLL, then probably you created a class library project.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I am just starting with C#, How do I create an executable? I googled and the answer was "Just compile it with visual studio"? This concept was simpler in C/C++

Comment: You can create different types of projects. Class Library projects produce a DLL. `Console App (.NET Framework)`, `Window Forms App (.NET Framework)`, `WPF App (.NET Framework)` all produce an EXE. If you want a simple hello world app, either use `Console App` or `Window Forms App`. They all just compile in VS.

Comment: It **did** create an executable. You may be considering only .exe files as executables, but that .dll file in there with the same name as your console application project is in fact the executable, it's just a .NET **Core** executable, which needs to be executed using the dotnet command. See the answer provided below for a way to create a Windows .exe executable as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume it's a dotnet core app since there is folder named `netcoreapp2.1`.

at the root of your project execute the following command to publish your app with executable files:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r <RID> --self-contained false
```

RID is the runtime identitfier, such as win-x64 or whatever platform you want to have build for.

If you want to get DLL then :

```
dotnet yourappname.dll
```

The "dll" file works across different platforms that are supported by the .net core runtime such windows, linux, and macOS.

If you want **to get the executable file on every Visual Studio build without firing any command**, then edit your `.csproj` file by adding the following line between `<PropertyGroup></PropertyGroup>` section:

```
  <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

now when you build there is a folder called `win10-x64` inside `netcoreapp2.1` that contains the executable.